# How to make a great reproducible example for Excel?

Tags: excel

Creating a general SO MCVE question is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more specifically for [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [Python's Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (as examples), but creating a MCVE doesn't seem as straightforward with Excel.

Frequently an Excel tagged question's examples are just a screenshot of a table and/or the formula bar, and repliciting a question or answer can be challenging and frustrating. Reproducable questions are more likely to get answers and are more useful to people that find them later.

How does one create a great, reproducible example for an Excel question?
Is it possible to create a minimal Excel table/dataset in a SO question?
How should formulas or chains of instructions be written?
What could be encouraged and what should be discouraged?

Comment: This would be a great question on the Meta site, but it doesn't fit here, because you're not asking an Excel question, but rather a question about to how to ask an Excel question.  Voting to migrate.

Comment: Sure, but I asked here simply because both the R and Pandas examples cited were well received on SO, and the hope (maybe mistaken) that if answered, someone asking a future question and needing help with it is more likely to find in on SO rather than Meta.

Comment: This is a discussion post that belongs on [meta], as Tim has pointed out. Your justification isn't really relevant; the question belongs on the other site, because it isn't a programming related question as defined in the site guidelines, and [meta] was specifically established for the purpose of hosting discussion based questions regarding the site. Future readers can be provided a link to the relevant [meta] post.

Comment: Using a [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) is one good way of providing the data for an example.